# DIfferent Definitions of relative Fitness

Tags: fitness

I have got a question concerning the definition(s) of relative fitness.

There seem to be two major definitions in the literature:

$$
\text{relative fitness 1} = \frac{\text{absolute fitness of a type}}{\text{average absolute fitness of all types in the given population}}
$$
$$
\text{relative fitness 2} = \frac{\text{absolute fitness of a type}}{\text{maximum absolute fitness in the given population}}
$$
Now, my question is: What difference does the different normalization make with respect to the calculation of long-term evolutionary dynamics in the most simple models?

In particular: While relative fitness 2 can be held constant over generations because it does not depend on the (changing) relative frequencies of the given types, relative fitness 1 depends on the (changing) relative frequencies of the given types and therefore cannot be held constant over generations - is this correct?

I hope one of you can help:)

Comment: It would help your question to provide sources/references for the different definitions you've found.